# Create HTML5 web database in project directory

Tags: java, database, html, web-sql

I am a newbie in using HTML5 web database. If I create a website using it and host it, different users will have their own different databases as the database is created in the user's local machine.

Is it possible to create a HTML5 web database in the project's directory itself so that every user will access the same database?

Specifically I need to use a programming language like Java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is, but you will need backend logic to make the connection with the database.

As a backend programation language you can use PHP, Python, Ruby, etc.. pair it with a framework, and it should be much more manageable..

I use python, and a framework, easy to use is [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Thanks alex for replying .. can it be used with java/jsp as well?

Comment: To use java, I think you should see JPA..
As well, the java programmers default framework for persistence is Hibernate.